# Regex Replace not working (error 445)

Tags: vba, excel

First of all i'm using office 2010

I have the vba script:

```
Function RegExpReplace(ByVal WhichString As String, _
                    ByVal Pattern As String, _
                    ByVal ReplaceWith As String, _
                    Optional ByVal IsGlobal As Boolean = True, _
                    Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As String
    'Declaring the object
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    'Initializing an Instance
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'Setting the Properties
    objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal
    objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive
    'Execute the Replace Method
    RegExpReplace = objRegExp.Replace(WhichString, ReplaceWith)

End Function
```

I tested it with sub:

```
Sub abc()
    Dim x
    x = RegExpReplace("123 foo 456 bar", "\d", "#")
End Sub
```

But i get an error 445 (Object does not support) at the line of

```
RegExpReplace = objRegExp.Replace(WhichString, ReplaceWith)
```

Can you tell me whats wrong?

I must use late binding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library** reference:

[image]

Also see below link:
http://mark.biek.org/blog/2009/01/regular-expressions-in-vba/

Comment: As i say, I cant import any library... I must use late binding.

Comment: @RoeyHaim What version of Excel are you using?  It works fine with me as well with Excel 2010

Comment: Hi, I'm using Excel 2010 running on PlayOnLinux (my workstation is Mint 17 xfce). The problem is only with the Replace function. other functions of the regex working fine.

Comment: @RoeyHaim did a little reading on late binding - I suspect that even the Replace function's object is looked up at runtime, you will still need a library for the code to recognize the object being created.  If that is not what you are looking for, I am afraid you will need to see if someone else has a solution for you, thanks